# AAD B2C - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am a guest user in one of the azure active directory B2C tenant.
I am trying to fetch users list using [azure](https://graph.windows.net) api.
While fetching that list, I am getting **"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"** exception.
Is it neccesary to have owner of that Azure B2C tenant to fetch users data or modify users data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  you cannot use a guest user with [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#). (I'm not sure what tool you used, so I assume that you were using Azure AD Graph Explorer.)

Second, according to the error massage, it means that **the account is not an administrator of that directory**. So,it doesn't have privileges to complete the operation.

**Solution:**

Try to use a internal account of that tenant and then assign it as a global admin:

Go to Azure portal > the B2C tenant > All users > select the user > Directory role > Change the role to a Global administrator > Save

Then you can succeed listing users  with that account.

Comment: One more thing, I am not able to add member other than guest user in group. Is there anything wrong? Can we add any member to any group?

Comment: Hi,@PankajDhote  ,Usually, we can add both guest users and internal users to one group. You can post a new question in SO with this new issue and more details about it, I believe we can help you resolve it.:-)

Comment: Sorry its my bad, Actually I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the settings in the directory.

An admin can go to Azure Active Directory -> User settings -> **Guest users permissions are limited**.

If that is turned on, guest users cannot enumerate users (i.e. access user lists).

Comment: You cannot sign in a guest user in Azure AD graph Explorer ,right?